# How can we filter the incoming transactions to a node to disable smart contract deployments?

Tags: contract-deployment, besu

How can we identify an incoming transaction that has to address as 0x0 so as to stop it from being mined and broadcasted in Hyperledger Besu? Can anyone tell a way to do it like any configurations to set or any change in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that natively with Besu.

One way would be customising the transaction pool to automatically exclude these transactions. It would not break consensus, even on mainnet as you are free to organise your pool as soon as tx sent to the network are valid from a network perspective. Making this change requires to modify Besu Java source code and build the executable by yourself.